# How to sort an array.length in fields of a collection using Indexe from firestore?

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I woud like to sort datas in a collection. This collection has multiple documents containing different fields.  One of the field(array) is containing different names. The length of the field (array) is different in each document.
I want to sort these documents depending on the length of this field (array). desc if possible.

I tried with firestore but i am not able to do it directly..

*Collection : names
Fields indexed: clientId Arrays likes Descending
query scope : Collection*

Should i add a new variable that count the number of names ? (I want to avoid it if possible)

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The length of the field (array) is different in each document. I want to sort these documents depending on the length of this field (array). desc if possible.

There is no way you can sort the documents in a collection based on the size of an array that exists as a property within the documents.

> Should I add a new variable that counts the number of names?

Currently, that's the only option you have. To answer your question, yes, you should add a new field named `count`, which should be incremented each time you add a new element in the array and decremented each time you remove an element from the array.